# Are EF code-first models intended to fully describe a database's structure?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-migration

I'm a little confused as to the purpose of a data model in Entity Framework code-first.  Because EF will auto-generate a database from scratch for you if it doesn't already exist using nothing more than the data model (including data annotations and Fluent API stuff in `DbContext.OnModelCreating`), I was assuming that the data model should fully describe your database's structure, and you wouldn't need to modify anything fundamental after that.

However, I came across [this Codeplex issue](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/57) in which one of the EF Triage Team members suggests that custom indexes be added in data migrations, but not as annotations to your data model fields, or Fluent API code.

But wouldn't that mean that anyone auto-generating the database from scratch would not get those custom indexes added to their DB?  The assumption seems to be that once you start using data migrations, you're never going to create the database from scratch again.  What if you're working in a team and a new team member comes along with a new SQL Server install?  Are you expected to copy over a database from another team member?  What if you want to start using a new DBMS, like Postgres?  I thought one of the cool things about EF was that it was DBMS-independent, but if you're no longer able to create the database from scratch, you can no longer do things in a DBMS-independent way.

For the reasons I outlined above, wouldn't adding custom indexes in a data migration but not in the data model be a bad idea?  For that matter, wouldn't adding any DB structure changes in a migration but not in the data model be a bad idea?

Comment: Certainly not. A SQL Server database offers much more than the generic capabilities of EF code first.

Answer (score 3):

> Are EF code-first models intended to fully describe a database's structure?

**No**, they don't fully describe the database structure or schema.Still there are methods to make the database fully described using EF. They are as below:

You can use the new CTP5’s `ExecuteSqlCommand` method on Database class which allows raw SQL commands to be executed against the database.

The best place to invoke `SqlCommand` method for this purpose is inside a `Seed` method that has been **overridden** in a custom `Initializer` class. For example:

```
protected override void Seed(EntityMappingContext context)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE INDEX IX_NAME ON ...");
}
```

You can even add Unique Constraints this way.
It is not a workaround, but will be enforced as the database will be generated.

**OR**

If you are badly in need of the attribute, then here it goes

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class IndexAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IndexAttribute(string name, bool unique = false)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.IsUnique = unique;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public bool IsUnique { get; private set; }
}
```

After this , you will have an initializer which you will call in your `OnModelCreating` method as below:

```
public class IndexInitializer<T> : IDatabaseInitializer<T> where T : DbContext
{
    private const string CreateIndexQueryTemplate = "CREATE {unique} INDEX {indexName} ON {tableName} ({columnName});";

    public void InitializeDatabase(T context)
    {
        const BindingFlags PublicInstance = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        Dictionary<IndexAttribute, List<string>> indexes = new Dictionary<IndexAttribute, List<string>>();
        string query = string.Empty;

        foreach (var dataSetProperty in typeof(T).GetProperties(PublicInstance).Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name == typeof(DbSet<>).Name))
        {
            var entityType = dataSetProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
            TableAttribute[] tableAttributes = (TableAttribute[])entityType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false);

            indexes.Clear();
            string tableName = tableAttributes.Length != 0 ? tableAttributes[0].Name : dataSetProperty.Name;

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in entityType.GetProperties(PublicInstance))
            {
                IndexAttribute[] indexAttributes = (IndexAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IndexAttribute), false);
                NotMappedAttribute[] notMappedAttributes = (NotMappedAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), false);
                if (indexAttributes.Length > 0 && notMappedAttributes.Length == 0)
                {
                    ColumnAttribute[] columnAttributes = (ColumnAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false);

                    foreach (IndexAttribute indexAttribute in indexAttributes)
                    {
                        if (!indexes.ContainsKey(indexAttribute))
                        {
                            indexes.Add(indexAttribute, new List<string>());
                        }

                        if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType || property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                        {
                            string columnName = columnAttributes.Length != 0 ? columnAttributes[0].Name : property.Name;
                            indexes[indexAttribute].Add(columnName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            indexes[indexAttribute].Add(property.PropertyType.Name + "_" + GetKeyName(property.PropertyType));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (IndexAttribute indexAttribute in indexes.Keys)
            {
                query += CreateIndexQueryTemplate.Replace("{indexName}", indexAttribute.Name)
                .Replace("{tableName}", tableName)
                .Replace("{columnName}", string.Join(", ", indexes[indexAttribute].ToArray()))
                .Replace("{unique}", indexAttribute.IsUnique ? "UNIQUE" : string.Empty);
            }
        }

        if (context.Database.CreateIfNotExists())
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
        }
    }

    private string GetKeyName(Type type)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(KeyAttribute), true) != null)
            return propertyInfo.Name;
        }
        throw new Exception("No property was found with the attribute Key");
    }
}
```

Then overload `OnModelCreating` in your DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new IndexInitializer<MyContext>());
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Apply the index attribute to your Entity type, with this solution you can have multiple fields in the same index just use the same name and unique.

**OR**

You can do the migrations later on.

**Note:**
I have taken a lot of this code from [here](http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2012/08/18/creating-indexes-via-data-annotations-with-entity-framework-5-0/).

Comment: Generally the recommendations here are solid . So +1 from me.   Im curious why you recommend in one option the Seed Override as a good place to create indexes.  Considering : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621  an approach based on the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext> ?  will attempt to build the indexes every time.  This a convient way agreed. But it has implications in a productive database.  So your last point "or" you can do migrations later... presumably you meant the highly managed approach  Update-Database command in Package Manager Console.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "do the migrations later on".  Once EF has created the up-to-date DB model, it doesn't make sense to apply the migrations.

Comment: @Jez Why doesn't it make sense according to you? otherwise, you are will have to eraze your database and create new one ...which i think you won't prefer...

Comment: This whole question of migrations is basically about when you create your DB from scratch; for whatever reason, you may want to do it.  Start afresh, new machine you're developing on, whatever.  So yes, erasing the DB and creating it from scratch is indeed what I'm talking about.  If it's such a bad idea, why does EF even allow you to automatically create the DB from scratch?

Comment: @Jez You are completely mistaken. Migrations allow you to change your database schema keeping the existing data intact. You can add more fields in the tables as well. But surely , be watchful for the foreignkey relationships while deleting previous fields in the tables of existing database.

Comment: @BhushanFirake I know that that's what migrations allow you to do; that's the point I'm trying to make.  If you have EF create the database for you, how can you "do the migrations later on" as you said?  There will be no need for those migrations any longer.

Comment: You should have given credit to http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2012/08/18/creating-indexes-via-data-annotations-with-entity-framework-5-0/

Comment: @GertArnold hey, nice and thankx for finding that out on internet. I had copied code from there from one of my projects and then utilising it most of the time an then forgot the link from where I had copied that. So , thanks for the original link. I  have edited my answer to put in the credits.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be if there is value in having migrations added mid-stream, or if those will cause problems for future database initializations on different machines.

The initial migration that is created also contains the entire data model as it exists, so by adding migrations (`enable-migrations` in the Package Manager Console) you are, in effect, creating the built-in mechanism for your database to be properly created down the road for other developers.

If you're doing this, I do recommend modifying the database initialization strategy to run all your existing migrations, lest EF should start up and get the next dev's database out of sync.

Something like this would work:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourNamespace.YourDataContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
```

So, no, this won't inherently introduce problems for future work/developers.  Remember that migrations are just turned into valid SQL that executes against the database...you can even use script mode to output the TSQL required to make the DB modifications based on anything in the migrations you have created.

Cheers.